# MVC Core Bind ViewModel to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have Customer transactional table with multiple lookup tables with foreign keys. We want to see the 3 table joined together and bind the ViewModel back to the Model and reverse.  I heard repositories should not access ViewModels.

(a) 
What is the proper software protocol for doing this? I do not want to use AutoMapper yet. Should I create a data access object or service, and can someone write a quick sample for me below? 
Should I create another folder called Data Service in MVC? I bought 3 MVC books and none of them discuss DTO or binding models <--> viewmodels.
Thanks,

**Repository:**

```
void GetByCustomerTransactionId()
{
   var result = from ct in CustomerTransaction
    join pt in ProductType on pt.ProductTypeId equals ct.ProductTypeId 
    join ss in Status on s.StatusId equals ct.StatusId 
    select new all fields
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
    public int ProductTypeId {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
    public int StatusID {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTypeTable
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; },
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; },
}

public class StatusType
{
    public int StatusId{ get; set; }
    public string StatusName{ get; set; },
    public string Description{ get; set; },

}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CustomerTransactionViewModel
    {
        public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
        public string ProductName {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
        public string ProductDescription {get; set; }, 
        public string StatusName {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTable
        public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
        public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
    }
```

Comment: DTO and ViewModel is essentially the same, just that the ViewModel has a little bit more purpose and often behavior (i.e. when used on Desktop Technologies such as WPF or validation attributes in case of MVC/WebApi). At one point you **HAVE** to map it. Either manually or with tools such as AutoMapper

Comment: Also keep in mind, that you only ever bind Model to ViewModel (or MOdel -> DTO, or Domain Model -> DTO/ViewModel) with Automapper, never the other way around. AutoMapper is not appropriate to bind to persistence or domain models, only from them. In case of the reverse way, you compose your models yourself (using new keyword and appropriately composing your objects and validating their state)

Comment: can you write a quick mapper function? is it just a public void function? Thanks,

Comment: started programming 2 months ago, so trying to learn MVC

Comment: @BlueLamp82 It seems to me that you have more than one question here. Two things - what is this `void GetByCustomerTransactionId()` (why void???) and I see you already have `ViewModel` in your question. Are you not happy with it or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you look into [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) is to map database object to view model. Is pretty neat and clean way.

If you do not want to use the AutoMapper, you might want to consider using static method.

```
var student = new Student { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
var mdoel = student.ToDTO();

public static StudentViewModel ToDTO(this Student student)
{
    var model = new StudentViewModel();
    model.FullName = $"{student.FirstName} {student.LastName}";
    return model;
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: can you one up my question also? for some reason voted down, thanks-

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CustomerTransactionViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
    public string ProductName {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
    public string ProductDescription {get; set; }, 
    public string StatusName {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTable
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
  // Every view model should always have mapper from dbmodel to vm.
  private void MaptoEntity(Entity e)
  {
    this.CustomerTransactionId = e.ID
    .....
    // this is also a repository that mapping db to view model.
    var prod = new ProductTypeViewModel().Load(e.ProductID);
    this.ProductName = prod.ProductName;
    this.ProductDescription = prod.ProductDescription;
    // so on.......
  }

  public bool Load(int id)
  {
   // Call data from DB.
    var entity = dbcontext.Entity.Find(id);
   // Map you from DB.
    this.MaptoEntity(entity)
  }
}
```

Better structure is create a Interface IViewModel that will require all the implementations.

Now you can call

```
var customerViewModel = new CustomerTransactionViewModel();
customerViewModel .Load(1);
```